# I want to access an array element without a ConstantInt LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm currently creating a compiler for my programming language. Each statement has a `codegen` method which generate the IR for it.
When creating the `codegen` method for the subscript expression (e.g. `array[i]`), I'm facing some issues. In order to get an element at an nth index, I used the `GetElementPtrInst`. When trying to do it with constant integers indices (e.g. 5: array[5]) it works perfectly, but with other llvm::Values like LoadInsts I get an error:
`Invalid GetElementPtrInst indices for type!`

LLVM version: Ubuntu LLVM v14.0.0

Comment: All but the last index of a getelementptr have to be constant, but if the type is an array, then the last index can be any integer Value. This should be enough for you, I think?

Comment: @arnt "All but the last index of a getelementptr have to be constant" Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you meant here, but that doesn't sound right to me. Struct indices need to be constant, but other than that you can put non-constant indices anywhere and as often you want in a GEP instruction. For example if you have a pointer to a struct in C and then do `p[i].x`, the resulting GEP will have the non-constant index (`i`) first and the constant one (`.x`) last. ...

Comment: ... And if you have a nested array (`int arr[N][M]`) and then do `arr[i][j]`, you will either have two indices that are both non-constant or one constant index (the 0 offset for the alloca or global variable) and then two non-constant indices.

Comment: @sepp2k you're right, I'm wrong. Sorry. Sloppy of me.